# Programming and evaluating Dijkstra algorithm

Tags: java, eclipse, computer-science, graph-algorithm

I have to do a project about shortest path algorithm. I am not really a professional I am just a normal student. I have to pick up first a problem ( train route, bus route, any travel route) then choose a suitable algorithm to solve it. Then I have to program it (using coding language java, python..) Then after that I should evaluate it(how speed is the algorithm, time complexity, etc) and if there is a better algorithm that I can be implement instead of what I chose first.

Choosing the problem is the hardest part as I 
Don't know what kind of problem I should explore to use of the algorithm!
Regards

Comment: Please clarify your question! And show us what you have done so far!

Comment: I clarify it.. hope its better now..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about picking which problem to do, rather than a question about issues that come up when working on one of them.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Are you making fun of me ? Noloader!! thank you anyways.. I just want to know what should I pick and then I should go deeper.. I think the website is all about (helping) others to Finnish what they are supposed to do!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take the city where you live in. Take any two bus stations, namely A and B, and the entire commuter network. This network is a graph. Stations are nodes, commuter connections between stations are edges (edge weight = time it takes the bus to travel between two stations).

Say, you want to travel from A to B in the shortest amount of time possible (you wont want to waste time, would you?).

Dijkstras Algorithm has as input the graph representing the commuter network and the node A and is able to deduce the shortest path from A to any other station (which includes the shortest path from A to B).

Does that help you? Wikipedia on Dijkstra has more detailed examples.

[image]

Comment: yes.. so I can use bus stations as vertices and edges is distance?

Comment: can i do it as distance instead of time ?

Comment: Yep, exactly. You *might* want to weight the edges by the time OR distance the travel takes (note that between vertices X and Y there is only an edge in my model if there is a *direct* bus connection between those stations=vertices)

Comment: Note that this is only an example and only one of inifinite models ;-) You could pretty much use anything as vertices and edges, Dijkstra will only find the shortest distance between one vertex and any other vertex. @user3236586

Comment: @user3236586 For playing around with it, JUNG2 has a decent implementation for Java.

Comment: what is best algorithm to use in this case?

Comment: dijkstra algorithm or A*?

Comment: @user3236586 Dijkstra is just a special case of A*. I wouldnt worry about A* too much, in practice the difference is just a few lines of code. In my experience, there are more internet resources on Dijkstra, even if Wikipedia should do the job for both. But thats just my opinion.

Comment: @user3236586 I should add that it *always* depends on your specific usecase. Which one runs faster is almost impossible to tell without going into very specific implementation details.

Comment: I included a graph of train route assume that vertices are the cities edges are that edges.. furthermore, I choose Dijkstra algorithm to program it.. it will take the shortest path from A to each node  so at the end we have a connected graph??

Comment: any recommended book?

Comment: @user3236586 What do you mean by "in the end you have"? Dijkstra doesn't modify the graph itself (the rest of your description is correct). Note that in some cases you have non-connected subgraphs (that might cause you headaches, the result depends on your implemetation, for example it could be infinite) (say, you cant reach Munich from New York by bus only).

Comment: and how can I know that the algorithm is faster then another by implementation?

Comment: @user3236586 What exactly do you intend to learn? Graph theory in general? Only Dijkstra? Regarding the algorithms, I personally found the description in Wikipedia and other online resources more helpful than books (but thats subjective)

Comment: @user3236586 Regarding performance, please read Java benchmarking tutorials. Basically (simplified) you should run them both on the same input and then compare how long they took (use an input that takes min. a few seconds to run)

Comment: I would like to know how to use graph programming in java.. specifically Dijkstra algorithm implementation.. thank you

Comment: @user3236586 I dont know any specific books off my hand, but JUNG2 (java graph library) provides a decent yet sometimes painfully slow framework for graph manipulation in Java. I think to maximize your learning effect you should use it and re-implement different algorithms like Dijkstra and then compare their Results with the JUNG2 output  http://jung.sourceforge.net/

Comment: what do you mean by " how long they took (use an input that takes min. a few seconds to run) " do u mean that how long it will run or what result it will output? can you explain please

Comment: @user3236586 Benchmarking means you find some way to create a, say 30000 node graph (that might take a few seconds to run Dijkstra on). Then you run implementation A on it and measure how long it takes to run. Then you do the same thing for implementation B. The problems is, if they run *really fast*, say 5 milliseconds, the results are difficult to compare. All that of course assumes that both implemenations run correctly (and that your intent is to find out which one is faster)

Comment: thank you so much for your help!! If I need something can I contact you here? yes/ NO :)

Comment: I cant guarantee I find time to answer, but sure you can ;-)